# Using local brew formula to install cross platform gcc compiler

Tags: gcc, homebrew

I need to install gcc cross compiler that generates ELF, and I found this site - http://time.to.pullthepl.ug/blog/2014/2/3/xv6-on-mac-os-x/

It points to a github for home-brew-gcc_cross_compilers (https://github.com/jinmel/homebrew-gcc_cross_compilers), and `put them in homebrew formulas`, but I'm not sure exactly how to put them in the formula.

Then, how to download the github code into home-brew formulas to invoke `brew install i386-elf-gcc`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory where the downloaded rb files are stored is `/usr/local/Library/Formula`, then run the brew command to install.

The log files can be found in `/Users/smcho/Library/Logs/Homebrew`.

Or, I could point to where the rb file is located.

```
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Gallopsled/pwntools-binutils/master/osx/binutils-$ARCH.rb
```

References

- https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Formula-Cookbook.md#formula-cookbook
- https://github.com/Gallopsled/pwntools-binutils/tree/master/osx
- http://pwntools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install/binutils.html